# Signal processing for undersampled signal

Tags: matlab, fft

I have got a set of pressure data from a boiler which has been sampled at 45Hz and I need to extract a frequency component of 250Hz from the signal. Using a standard FFT method doesn't display anything apart from frequency components between 0 and 10Hz.

I have read similar questions posted on the forum with no success in solving my problem.

```
%Matlab code

filename = 'boilerp.xlsx';
columnA = xlsread(filename,'A:A');

Fs =45;

L=length(columnA);

nfft = 2^nextpow2(L);

XT = fft(columnA, nfft)/L;

f= Fs/2*linspace(0,1,nfft/2+1);

plot(f, 2*abs(XT(1:nfft/2+1)))
```

Many thanks,

Khel

Comment: If an anti-aliasing filter was applied to the signal before sampling, then you will not be able to recover the 250Hz signal.  If a bandpass was applied before sampling, you might be able to recover the 250Hz signal.  What do you know about the processing that was done before the sampling?

Comment: Thank you. I would not be able to apply bandpass filter before sampling due to the limitation of my system- at the moment I can only process the output data of 40Hz sampling rate. There is no processing done before sampling - it is just sampling the raw data at 40Hz.

Comment: How are you sampling the pressure data?  How long does it take for each sample to be taken?  Normally, your ADC (analog to digital converter) will have some kind of antialiasing filter built into it.  There are some without (like the ADC on some microcontrollers,) but it would help to know as much about the system as possible.

Comment: The conditioning of the signal is performed by the sensor without any filtering. The sensor is able to output the signal at much higher frequency but my system is only sampling it at 45Hz.

Comment: Do you by chance record a precise timing information at sampling? If there are small irregularities, then you can find options in non-regular sampling processing

Comment: Your 250 Hz signal will either be aliased or absent, depending on the sensor circuitry.  If it's aliased, you may still be able to do useful things with it, but you need to specify clearly what you want to do with that signal and how it was sensed.

Answer (score 1):

Combining @JRE's comment and @Nikita's answer: if no anti-aliasing filter was applied to the signal, and no other frequencies alias to 20 Hz, then the 250 Hz component you're interested in will appear at 20 Hz in your sampled signal. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing#Sampling_sinusoidal_functions for more information on how this works.

Comment: Thanks Nikita and MBaz. Depending on the operation of the system, there might be other frequency components higher than 250Hz within the signal which I am not aware of. I am not sure how I can apply this without knowing the maximum frequency of the system.

Answer (score 0):

According to Kotelnikov theorem, maximum frequency represented by a sampled signal is Fs/2, so there is no frequency of 250 Hz in the signal sampled by 45 Hz. I suggest center frequency of the original signal is 6*Fs=270 Hz. In this case, 250 Hz corresponds to -20 Hz for sampled signal.

Comment: it would then alias again at DC and become +20 Hz